# How do I use an existing Redis connection in Vanity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, unicorn, vanity

I have a Redis add-on in Heroku that only allows 10 connections. My app already uses Redis with `$redis`. I have Unicorn with 3 workers and 2 dynos, which is 6 connections. Vanity connects by itself which is another 6 connections. That is 12 connections which is over the limit of 10. How do I use the existing `$redis` connection for Vanity so Vanity and my app share the connection?

I saw this deprecated method, but when I try it, it gives an error and stack trace. It was probably for an old version of Redis client.

http://rdoc.info/gems/vanity/Vanity/Playground#redis%3D-instance_method

I use `establish_connection` in my Unicorn.rb file to connect, and pass it the connection string. I would like to set the connection or Redis client object directly.

http://rdoc.info/gems/vanity/Vanity/Playground#establish_connection-instance_method

Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.0.3, Vanity 1.9.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Vanity `Playground` object programmatically and pass in a Redis adapter with an existing `redis` instance.

```
Vanity.playground.establish_connection { :adapter => :redis, :redis => $redis }
```

This is specified in the [vanity configuration guide](https://github.com/assaf/vanity/blob/master/doc/configuring.textile).

Comment: Wow I had no idea it could take a hash. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Happy to help.  Would love an upvote and mark it answered if this solves your problem.